# SIMPLS - partial least squares

Tags: statistics, reference-request, algorithms, data-analysis

I am currently learning partial least squares analysis. I understand the idea, and the method I know to get PLS is NIPALS. Since I am currently writing a paper about this subject, I want to learn SIMPLS as well, but I can’t find any article or book (free) to learn this algorithm properly.

Is anyone familiar with this method or knows where I can learn it?

Thank you in advance.